# Updating Parent Fragment from Child Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my android application, I have two Fragments. Parent Fragment contains list of available Filter Types and when a particular Filter Type is clicked (in Parent Fragment - Yellow Background) corresponding Child Fragment (Pink Background) opens with list of available options for selected filter type. My requirement is once User select/deselect an option in child fragment, it should reflect/update option count (Green color) in parent Fragment.

Please check attached wireframe.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Otto Bus for comunications between Fragments, fragments-activities, services, etc.

Maybe, the first time you can be a little weird if you have not used before but it is very powerful and very easy to use. You can find the library and a tutorial here:

http://square.github.io/otto/

An example. In your adapter or where you have your item click event you cand send a Object by the Bus.

In your bus you invoque the post method and pass the object. (I recommended create a singleton for Bus).

The singleton Bus Provider.

```
/**
 * Canal de comunicacion
 */
public class BusProvider {

    private static final Bus REST_BUS = new Bus(ThreadEnforcer.ANY);
    private static final Bus UI_BUS = new Bus();

    private BusProvider() {};

    public static Bus getRestBusInstance() {
        return REST_BUS;
    }

    public static Bus getUIBusInstance () {
        return UI_BUS;
    }
}
```

You send a Object in the bus (in your child fragment) like this:

```
BusProvider.getUIBusInstance().post(itemSelected);
```

And in your parent fragment you subscribe for this event:

```
@Subscribe
public void activitySelected(final Item itemSelected) {

}
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Thanks Bus is a great way communicate. But once I receive event on ParentFragment, there is no way to update FilterCount, as Filter count is part of ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Even though my answer might be late, I guess it still could help :

The solution is simple, in case you need to access a parent fragment from a child one, then use a specific tag for the parent when adding it to the stack, like in the following code example :

1) In the containing activity :

```
// We instanciate the parent fragment
ParentFragment parentFragment = new ParentFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

// We add the parent fragment with a tag, so we can use it later to fetch 
// the current instance of the parent fragment from the child fragment
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, parentFragment, "parent_fragment_tag");

ft.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit transaction
ft.commit();
```

2) In the child fragment, we get the current parent fragment instance like this :

```
Fragment parentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("parent_fragment_tag");
```

I hope this answer can be of help.